# Why DACL entries of a file printed via win32 API is not matching up with DACL information in the file properties?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Here is the minimal code for reference

```
 ULONG result = GetSecurityInfo(Hfile
        , SE_FILE_OBJECT
        , OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION |GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION| DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION 
        , &sidowner
        , &sidgroup
        , &pdacl
        , NULL
        , &psd);
```

This is how I extracted the access control entries from DACL

```
BOOL b = GetAce(pdacl, i, (LPVOID*)&ace); 
        if (((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*)ace)->Header.AceType == ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE) {

            sid = (PSID)&((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*)ace)->SidStart;

            LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid, oname, &namelen, doname, &domainnamelen, &peUse);
            wcout << "domianName/AccoutName : " << doname << "/" << oname << endl;

            mask = ((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*)ace)->Mask;
            cout << "Allowed" << endl;
        }
```

output:

```
domianName/AccoutName : BUILTIN/Administrators
Allowed
 

    DELETE
     FILE_GENERIC_READ
     FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
     FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
     READ_CONTROL
     WRITE_DAC
     WRITE_OWNER
     SYNCHRONIZE
    
    domianName/AccoutName : BUILTIN/Administrators
    Allowed
     DELETE
     FILE_GENERIC_READ
     FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
     FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
     READ_CONTROL
     WRITE_DAC
     WRITE_OWNER
     SYNCHRONIZE
    
    domianName/AccoutName : BUILTIN/Administrators
    Allowed
     DELETE
     FILE_GENERIC_READ
     FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
     FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
     READ_CONTROL
     SYNCHRONIZE
    
    domianName/AccoutName : BUILTIN/Users
    Allowed
     FILE_GENERIC_READ
     FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
     FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
     READ_CONTROL
     SYNCHRONIZE
```

As we can see from the above output Administrators have multiple entries and ACE of "System" and "Authenticated users" are not found. "Users" only have read rights in file properties but in the output, it is printed that the "Users" have "Write access" as well.

I did a lot of research and read through many books but nothing seems to give a clear-cut answer

edit:
Here's the output using the `CACLS` command.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>cacls e:/hello.txt
e:\hello.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:F
             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F
             NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:C
             BUILTIN\Users:R
```

Comment: Can you please show to what you compare the DACL? In your code you only seem to show `ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE`. Maybe one of the ACEs is a denial ACE type?

Comment: @Werner Henze I have the ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE as well

else if (((ACCESS_DENIED_ACE*)ace)->Header.AceType == ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE) {
            sid = (SID*)&((ACCESS_DENIED_ACE*)ace)->SidStart;
            LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid, oname, &namelen, doname, &domainnamelen, &peUse);
            wcout << "domianName/AccoutName : " << doname << "/" << oname << endl;
            mask = ((ACCESS_DENIED_ACE*)ace)->Mask;
            cout << "Deined" << endl;
}

Comment: You say "is not matching up with DACL information in the file properties?" but you don't show that part. So we can't compare what you get and what you expect. Please read [mcve] and add the "expected behaviour" part.

Comment: @Werner Henze Since I am new to StackOverflow I cannot paste images for the GUI(File properties). But for your reference, it is the default DACL information contained by most windows systems for a text file. Admins should have full control, SYSTEM should have full control, authenticated users should have "MOdify" and users should have "read & execute". This is the minimal reproducible I can produce with my account. I have linked my full code as well since you asked [link](https://github.com/BrightonJoel/Zoho-task-1) `code`

Comment: Does LookupAccountSid always succeed? Or does it give an error and not change the output buffers?

Comment: You could show the output of the command line tool `cacls`.

Comment: @WernerHenze Thank you for pointing out. here is the output of that e:\hello.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:F
             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F
             NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:C
             BUILTIN\Users:R

Comment: @user253751 my apologies for not checking it does throw an error every time how could I solve this.  It throws this error **The data area passed to a system call is too small. **

Comment: @BrightonJoel what is the error?

Comment: @user253751 The error is **"The data area passed to a system call is too small. "**

Comment: @BrightonJoel then consider making the data area big enough

Comment: @user253751 like this wchar_t* oname = new TCHAR[512]; ?

Comment: @BrightonJoel how does the function LookupAccountSid know how big oname is?

Comment: @user253751 please don't be offended if I ask silly questions I'm new to this win32api. How can we make the data area big? here is my full if you want to see it. [link](https://github.com/BrightonJoel/Zoho-task-1)`code`

Comment: @BrightonJoel I suggest the problem is not the actual size of the data area, but the size your program is *telling* LookupAccountSid. How does the function LookupAccountSid know how many TCHARs you allocated for oname - how did you tell it that?

Comment: @user253751 just a guess.  should I somehow change &namelen or something.

Comment: @BrightonJoel you should answer the question - it's not a trick question - how does your program tell LookupAccountSid that you allocated 512 TCHARs for oname?

Comment: @user253751 I guess it does not tell it to the lookupAccoutsid.

Comment: Are you forgetting to take inheritence into account?

Comment: @BrightonJoel Of course it does. Otherwise how would LookupAccountSid know whether the data area was large enough? And if it didn't know, someone could crash any program by making a really long username. Have you read the manual for LookupAccountSid? Not a trick question.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I even tried to assign the permission explicitly too it still doesn't work

Comment: @user253751 I saw the Microsoft docs it says cchName tells the function the size of TCHAR. but still, I am perplexed about how to increase the size of the data I just tried increasing it by this way "wchar_t* oname = new TCHAR[512]" but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @BrightonJoel What number is in cchName the first time you call LookupAccountSid? What about the second time? Is it still the same number?

Comment: @user253751 first time namelen = 14 and domainlen = 7, second time namelen = 7 and domainlen = 13 (account name fetching failed)

Comment: @BrightonJoel Before or after the call? I meant before

Comment: @user253751 AFter the call. BTW can we chart in email or something before they kick us out for conversing in comments

Comment: @BrightonJoel and before?

Comment: @user253751 oh thank you so much that solves the problem. The before was the problem after I reassign in every time after the function call I get the desired output

Comment: It seems the output of `cacls` was cut off in the comment. Can you please add that to the question itself. It is relevant information and thus should be added to the question and not be hidden in a comment.

Comment: @BrightonJoel If others wouldn't post an answer you're expected to answer yourself in order to someone which encounters the same circumstance can refer to.

Comment: @WernerHenze I will update the question thanks for pointing out

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Thank you for informing. Still some parts of the question remain unsolved after I find or have the complete solution I will update the perfect answer.

Comment: @user253751 Another problem is that "Users" in the `CACLS` output only have read and read& execute permission but in the Winapi output the "Users" seem to have "FILE GENERIC WRITE " permission as well. why is that?

Comment: @BrightonJoel It's not winapi output, it's your program output. What causes your program to print "FILE GENERIC WRITE"?

Comment: @user253751 why it is happing like that in my program? `if(FILE_GENERIC_WRITE & ace->Mask)` This is what did to check whether the "User" has File Generic write I did the same for all the permissions too.

Comment: @BrightonJoel what value is FILE_GENERIC_WRITE? (you can look it up) and what do you suppose `((FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA) & FILE_READ_DATA)` is - is it true or false?

Comment: @user253751 the operation you mention will return the same value as FILE_READ_DATA which would be true. 0x120116 is the value of FILE_GENERIC_WRITE. FILE_GENERIC_WRITE consists of STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE | FILE_WRITE_DATA | FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_WRITE_EA |     FILE_APPEND_DATA | SYNCHRONIZE

Comment: @BrightonJoel so you see that if the file has any of those permissions, for example if it has SYNCHRONIZE, then your program will print FILE_GENERIC_WRITE

Comment: @user253751 It doesn't check if the user has all permissions of FILE_GENERIC_WRITE but rather my code check if the user has at least one of the permissions. It makes sense thanks once again user253751.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the question:

The reason why the program prints the name same account name repeatedly is because the `LookupAccountSid` function does not have enough data area. since the `namelen` and `domainlen` are `IN\OUT` arguments the function returns the size of the domain name and account name every time after execution. So to solve this the `namelen` and `domainlen` have to be reassigned every time.

```
LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid, oname, &namelen, doname, &domainnamelen, &peUse);
wcout << "domianName/AccoutName : " << doname << "/" << oname << endl;
namelen = 100; domainnamelen = 100; //This should solve the problem
```

Here is the link to the docs for the [LookupAccountSid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsidw) function

The second part of the question

The reason why the output from the program shows the users have `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` permission even though the `CACLS` seem to show that users only have read and execute permission to the given file path is that in the program the code that checks if the users have the `write permissions` is done by the following.

```
if (FILE_GENERIC_WRITE & ace->Mask) {
    wcout << " FILE_GENERIC_WRITE" << "\n";
}
```

The problem is the `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE` consists of multiple permissions like `STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE | FILE_WRITE_DATA | FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_WRITE_EA | FILE_APPEND_DATA | SYNCHRONIZE` and when the code is written like this `(FILE_GENERIC_WRITE & ace->Mask)` it only checks if at least one of the permissions is present or not.

A special thanks to [@user253751](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/user253751) and [@Werner Henze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023911/werner-henze) for patiently explaining the solution